# Unity Scriptable Object Assigned value not updated in runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I'm using a scriptable object as my units database, and each unit has it's own UnitStats script to load stats from the database in Start() method. It works all fine until today when I make changes to variables in the scriptable data, the variables loaded in UnitStats script are unchanged. For example, the original maxHP in scriptable data is 100, I run, UnitStats load maxHP = 100, then I change maxHP to 110 in the scriptable data, I run, UnitStats maxHP is still 100.

I tried saving the project, committing changes to Unity version control, restarting Unity, maxHP in the scriptable object remains 110 but the loaded value in UnitStats is still 100.

Here's my UnitStats script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class UnitStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public string unitName;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float attackRange;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float movementSpeed;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int maxHP;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int currentHP;
    [HideInInspector]
    public string type;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float attackInterval; 
    [HideInInspector]
    public int priority;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int dpa;
    //[HideInInspector]
    public int searchRange;
    [SerializeField] UnitDatabaseSO unitDatabase;
    [SerializeField] int ID;
    public Dictionary<GameObject, int> abilities;
    private UnitData unitData;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool loaded;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float damageTime;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool ranged;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float buildTime;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Sprite spriteIcon;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int visionRange;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int bloodDrop;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int bloodCost;
    [HideInInspector]
    public string description;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isWorker;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int MaxBloodPool;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int bloodAmount;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float height;

    void Start(){
        if(!loaded){
            unitData = unitDatabase.objectsData[ID];
            unitName = unitData.Name;
            attackRange = unitData.AttackRange;
            movementSpeed = unitData.MovementSpeed;
            maxHP = unitData.maxHP;
            currentHP = maxHP;
            type = unitData.Type;
            attackInterval = unitData.AttackInerval;
            priority = unitData.Priority;
            dpa = unitData.DPH;
            searchRange = unitData.SearchRange;
            damageTime = unitData.DamageTime;
            ranged = unitData.ranged;
            spriteIcon = unitData.SpriteIcon;
            buildTime = unitData.buildTime;
            visionRange = unitData.VisionRange;
            bloodDrop = unitData.BloodDrop;
            bloodCost = unitData.BloodCost;
            description = unitData.Description;
            isWorker = unitData.IsWorker;
            MaxBloodPool = unitData.MaxBloodPool;
            bloodAmount = 0;
            height = unitData.height;
            loaded = true;
        }
        HPBarManager.instance.CreateHPBar(transform, currentHP/maxHP);
    }

    public void AssignID(int ID){
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    public void ReceiveDmg(GameObject source, int damage){
        currentHP -= damage;
        if(currentHP <= 0){
            GetComponent<UnitStateMachine>().TransitState(UnitStateMachine.Unitstate.Dead);
            return;
        }
        HPBarManager.instance.UpdateHPBar(transform, currentHP/maxHP);
    }


    public void GainHP(int heal){
        if(currentHP + heal >= maxHP){
            currentHP = maxHP;
        }else{
            currentHP += heal;
        }
        HPBarManager.instance.UpdateHPBar(transform, currentHP/maxHP);
    }

    public bool IsDead(){
        return currentHP <= 0;
    }

    public int GetID(){
        return ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware Scriptable Objects cannot be modified at runtime

Comment: @A-Fairooz I'm not trying to modify it at runtime. I have a UnitStats script that loads data from the scriptable object at run time. The problem is that the data loaded does not match the data I have in the scriptable object.

Comment: Could you share the code you're using to load your stats? By the sounds of it, it's most likely not loading your stats from the scriptable object AT ALL and is just using a your default value for that variable, either that or you're overwriting it with another value.

Comment: I just edited in the UnitStats script. The script does not have any default value, the only value I assigned in the inspector is ID. Also I have 3 different units in the scene sharing the same UnitStats script, and their values are different. The search range is the newly added variable(always 0 no matter what I set in the database), which leads me to find this problem.

Comment: If you have a value that isn't changing in response to changing your database value, it leads me to believe that either you're not referencing the correct database, or you're referencing the wrong item in that database

Comment: That's what I thought too. But I checked at least 3 times there is only 1 UnitDatabase, and it is the one assigned to UnitStats, ID of the unit is set to 0 in the inspector, the UnitStats script loads data based on ID(index in the database), the data I'm trying to load is the first item in the database. I tried logging the database value(maxHP) in the UnitStats script, it outputs the old value(100 instead of what it is currently set to).

Comment: That's very odd, the only other thing I could suggest is to create a custom get set, you'll need a private variable called `_maxHP`, and your maxHP would then be `public int maxHP { get => _maxHP; set { _maxHP = value; Debug.Log(value); } }` by using this whenever your `maxHP` is modified a debug message will appear so you know that it's getting updated, this way you'll be able to catch if there's another function overriding your initialization.

Comment: Thank for the tip. I tried your method, set is only called once, and it is set to the database value, but when I try to access this value with other scripts using GetComponent<>().maxHP, it is getting the old value(100). Also I noticed that when I remove the [HideInInspector], maxHP is set to 100, so I'm guessing somehow the inspector value override the value set in Start()?

Comment: Found the problem, for some reason I set loaded to true in the inspector and hid it for the unit I'm testing. And there is another unit sitting in the corner which I completely forgot about giving me all the logs. Now I feel so dumb lol.